# Is there a way to tell whether or not minimal logging occurred for a sql query?

Tags: sql-server

I have been using this page to tell me which insert options should and should not lead to minimal logging: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx

Is there a way to verify whether or not minimal logging has actually occurred after I run queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use `fn_dblog()`<sup>1</sup> to read the relevant log records based on `AllocUnitName`, and make educated guesses based on the row counts and `[log record size]` values. So, perform your operation (say, on a target table of `dbo.MyTable`), and then check the results of:

```
SELECT Operation, Context, [Log Record Length]
  INTO #foo
  FROM sys.fn_dblog(null, null) 
  WHERE AllocUnitName + '.' LIKE N'dbo.MyTable.%';
```

Then query against the data you find in `#foo` ([the sort operator you will typically see, as in this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/02/05/bulk-logging-optimizations-minimal-logging.aspx), makes this query quite expensive and time consuming).

The `Log Record` and five `RowLog Contents x` columns might be interesting too, but not sure how much effort you want to put into reverse engineering those.

> <sup>*1. this function is unsupported and undocumented.*</sup>

Comment: I am finding that if the table has a clustered index, I need to look for allocunitname = N'schemaname.tablename.clusteredindexname'